# Fourier transform of $1/\sin(a x)$?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

The function $1/\sin(a x)$ with parameter $a\in\mathbb{R}$ is periodic in the argument $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Does a Fourier transform for it exist, and is it known?

The infinite values might pose a problem. If so, how about the function $1/(\sin(a x)+ib)$ with a complex shift by an extra parameter $b\in\mathbb{R}$ which makes the function finite at all $x$.

What is the Fourier transform of any of these functions?

Comment: Do you know what is a distribution, the principal value $pv.(\frac{1}{x})$, and the periodic distributions ?

Comment: @reuns I do know distributions, the Cauchy principal value and can imagine how to compose periodic distributions out of simple ones. Is there a way to apply this to get the Fourier transform in this case? If so, could you please elaborate?

Comment: The Fourier transform is $\sum_n c_n \delta(\omega-an)$. You can find the $c_n$ directly by solving $(\delta(\omega-a)-\delta(\omega+a)) \ast \sum_n c_n \delta(\omega-an) = \delta(\omega)$, or you can use some complex analysis to evaluate the Fourier series coefficients $pv. \int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac{e^{-inx}}{\sin(x)}dx = pv. \int_{|z|=1} \frac{2 z^{1-n}}{z-z^{-1}}dz =  \int_{|z|=1+\epsilon} \frac{ z^{1-n}}{z-z^{-1}}dz+ \int_{|z|=1-\epsilon} \frac{ z^{1-n}}{z-z^{-1}}dz$,

Comment: @reuns From my calculations, the Fourier transform of $f(x)=1/\sin(\pi x)$ comes out to be $\tilde{f}(w)=i\sum_{m=-\infty}^\infty e^{i m(\pi+w)}$, simply from taking anti-derivative of $e^{i x w}/\sin(\pi x)$ in $x$ (which is $-\frac{2e^{i(\pi+w)x}}{\pi+w}{}_2F_1(1,\frac{\pi+w}{2\pi},\frac{3\pi+w}{2\pi},e^{2\pi i x})$) and summing principal value differences at $x=m+0^+$ and $x=m+0^-$. Could you explain why you expect the result to be sum of delta distributions?

Comment: The [Dirac comb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_comb) is its own Fourier transform.

Comment: @reuns Wow! But... if the Dirac comb is its own Fourier transform, and it is equal to the Fourier transform of $1/\sin(\pi x)$, then $1/\sin(\pi x)$ must be the Dirac comb! That does not seem right since each $\delta$ is symmetric while $\sin$ is anti-symmetric. Am I missing something?

Comment: The correct result should be $-i|a| \sum_n \text{sign}(n) e^{i  a n x}$. See my 2nd comment

Comment: @reuns So you are saying that $1/\sin(a x)=-i|a|\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \text{sign}(n)e^{ianx}$? This is a very interesting formula! I assume it should be known in the literature (unless you were the first one to derive it right now!), but trying to search online I can't seem to find it. Perhaps you know of a reference?

Comment: There was a typo. And no. I'm saying that $pv.(\frac{1}{\sin(x)})=-i\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \text{sign}(2n+1)e^{i(2n+1)x}$ **in the sense of distributions**, ie. $pv. \int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac{\varphi(x)}{\sin(x)}dx = -i\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \text{sign}(2n+1)b_{2n+1}$ where $b_n = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi  \varphi(x)e^{-inx}dx$ whenever $\varphi$ is $C^\infty$ (or $C^1$) and $2\pi$-periodic.

Comment: @reuns Turns out I lost a $\text{sign}(w)$ in my anti-derivative calculation somewhere. But with the appropriate sum representation of $1/\sin(x)$ the Fourier transform is very easy to obtain! See my answer below.

Comment: @reuns OK, the sum representation trick was aesthetically a bit unsatisfactory. I added a derivation via residues to the answer, in case if you're interested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the following identity

$$\begin{align}
\csc (x)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{x-n\pi}
\end{align}$$

which was proven in [another discussion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1419280/series-of-cscx-or-sinx-1/1419325#1419325) here on stackexchange.

With this it is trivial to take the Fourier transform term by term:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx \csc(x)e^{iwx}=i\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\text{sign}(w)\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}e^{i\pi n(1+w)}$$

Note that due to the $\text{sign}(w)$ in front this is actually not the Dirac comb.

**EDIT**

There is also a very simple way to derive the result from residues:

The integral $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx \csc(x)e^{iwx}$ naturally has holes at all positions $x=\pi n$ with $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, to even be defined (since integers are a set of zero measure with respect to the real line, it is still the full Fourier transform).

If $w>0$ (or $w<0$) we can close the contour at its far ends via the upper (or lower) half plane. This adds zero contribution to the integral due to [Jordan's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%27s_lemma).

Then deforming the half circle contour back to the real line, we cancel all contributions from the initial integral and are left with just tiny half-circles around each $x=\pi n$ point in counter-clockwise (or clockwise) direction.

The half-circles contribute half a residue each. Counter-clockwise gives positive residue while clockwise gives negative residue, therefore we immediately find a $\text{sign}(w)$ term to be multiplied with the result.

Since $1/\sin(x)$ only has simple poles, we trivially have:

$$\frac{2\pi i}{2}\text{res}_{x=\pi n}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \csc(x)e^{iwx}\right)=i\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}e^{i\pi n(1+w)}$$

So that again, the full result properly is

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx \csc(x)e^{iwx}=i\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\text{sign}(w)\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}e^{i\pi n(1+w)}.$$

Comment: You need to mention the principal values. And you can obtain the result directly from $pv.(\frac{1}{\sin(x)}) = \frac{1}{2}\lim_{a \to 0^+} \frac{1}{\sin(x+ia)}+\frac{1}{\sin(x-ia)}$ and expand $\frac{2i}{\sin(z)}=\frac{1}{e^{z} - e^{-z}}$ as a geometric series in $e^{z}$ or $e^{-z}$ depending on $\Im(z)$.

Comment: An equivalent method is to start from the  Fourier series $pv.(\frac{1}{\cos(x)}) = \sum_n c_n e^{i n x}$ (which converges in the sense of distributions). Then $1=\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2} pv.(\frac{1}{\cos(x)}) =\sum_n \frac{c_{n-1}+c_{n+1}}{2} e^{i n x}$ thus For $n \ne 0$ : $c_{n+1} = - c_{n-1}$ and for $n= 0$ : $c_1+c_{-1} = 2$, ie. ...

Comment: @reuns Interesting! How come the principal values are taken from a complex direction when the contour is purely real though? (I believe saying that the initial contour has holes at the pole locations accounts for $pv.$).

Comment: If $F$ has a pole at $t= 0$ then $pv. \int_{-1}^1 F(t)g(t)dt \overset{def}= \lim_{a \to 0^+} \int_{-1}^{-a}+\int_a^1 F(t)g(t)dt$ or when $h$ has many poles. It works the same way for $pv.\int_\gamma f(z)dz = pv.\int_0^1 f(\gamma(t)) \gamma'(t)dt$. And if $f$ is meromorphic then $pv.\int_\gamma f(z)dz = \frac{1}{2}  \int_{\gamma_a}+\int_{\gamma_{-a}} f(z)dz$ where $\gamma_a,\gamma_{-a}$ are contours with a small enough identation around the pole.