# Is this a good approximation for $\sec x$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

By the asymptotes of $\tan x$, I came up with
$$\tan x \stackrel{?}{=}(\sin x)\Bigg(\sum_{n=-\infty}^{
\infty}\cfrac{(-1)^n}{x-\frac{(2n-1)\pi}{2}}\Bigg)$$
So does $\sec x$ equal $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{
\infty}\cfrac{(-1)^n}{x-\frac{(2n-1)\pi}{2}}$? Or this is already a well known series representation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Series of $\csc(x)$ or $(\sin(x))^{-1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1419280/series-of-cscx-or-sinx-1)

Answer (score 0):

It is well-known, yes. It can be obtained through the logarithmic derivative of Euler's product formula for sine (i.e. its Weierstrass factorization). And yes, it is a convenient approximation. See [MSE Q1419280](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1419280/).