# Fourier series and partial fraction expansion of πcsc(πz)/z

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, partial-fractions

Having trouble with this question involving the Fourier series and partial fraction expansion.

I need to prove
$$
z\sum_{n\in Z }{\frac{(-1)^n}{z^2-n^2} } = π\csc(πz)
$$

I think I should start by solving the Fourier series at $z=0$ and $z=π$ and gathering together what is real to get the desired answer.

Comment: Did you mean to type $(-1)^n$? And do you mean $z=0$ and $z=\pi$?

Comment: @Accelerator Yes my mistake! (-1)^n is what I meant and z = 0 and z = π

Comment: [Does this help?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1419280/series-of-cscx-or-sinx-1/1419325#1419325)

Comment: @Accelerator Yes! Thank you!